# How to filter api response in Angular

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

Work on Asp.net mvc.As i am new in angular js.Stuck on basic issue,want to know how to filter api result in angular.**services1** and **services2** get respectively **serviceId=1** and **serviceId=2** datas.My filter criteria is ServiceId

**Here is my angular syntax**

```
MyPageService.GetOthersByID('/api/XXXXXX/GetServiceUsableBalance').success(function (data) {


    $scope.services1 = arr1;
    $scope.services2 = arr2;
    }
```

**Bellow is my Api response.**

```
LiveCustomerMT4ServiceID CustomerID    ServiceID   ServiceInstanceID    UserNa
------------------------ -------------------- ----------- -------------------- ---
7                        40                   2           2015052672           
8                        40                   1           2015052672           
9                        40                   2           2015052672           
9                        40                   1           2015052672
```

Angular invoke api successfully and also get response but failed to filter success response.

Comment: What's your filter criteria? Not getting exactly what do you want?

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript **filter()** function:

```
$scope.services1 = data.filter(element => element.serviceId == 1);
$scope.services2 = data.filter(element => element.serviceId == 2);
```

Comment: filter is not a function I get.

Answer (score 0):

Following is the demo to get result as per your request:-

```
MyPageService.GetOthersByID('/api/XXXXXX/GetServiceUsableBalance').success(function (data) {
   $scope.services1 = $filter('filter')(data, { serviceID: 1 }, true);
   $scope.services2 = $filter('filter')(data, { serviceID: 2 }, true);
});
```

*Note:- Please don't forget to inject $filter to your controller*